# Why is 2 / -2 / 2 equal to -2 in OpenSCAD? (Mathematical Order of Operations)

Tags: openscad

Recently I have been doing more complicated math in OpenSCAD and I have run into something that I find strange. Take a simple math expression: `2 / 2 / 2`. By any programming language this will equal 0.5 (1/2), and OpenSCAD agrees. Something like this: `2 / -2 / 2` should also be -0.5 for the same reason. However, OpenSCAD thinks this is -2. That is `echo(2 / -2 / 2);` gives `ECHO: -2`. My calculator, other programming languages (and myself) all say its -0.5.

Is this a quirk of OpenSCAD, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Check what (2 / -2) gets you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect the behavior you are seeing is an undocumented feature (aka, bug) of OpenSCAD. I've found in the latest stable release that if the - is placed on either end, the result is -0.5, but in the middle, my results are the same as yours. Surrounding the -2 with parentheses results in a correct answer, however.

It appears that the parentheses turns a mathematical operation into a signed integer. It follows that the operations without the parentheses is right to left:

2/2 = 1, negative 1 with the minus, 2/-1 = -2

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/openscad/openscad/issues/2894

Comment: And there's now a [fix for the issue](https://github.com/openscad/openscad/pull/2895) merged into master. Nightly builds should handle this correctly from here on out.

Answer (score 4):

I [filed this issue as a bug with the OpenSCAD project](https://github.com/openscad/openscad/issues/2894), and there is now [a fix merged into master](https://github.com/openscad/openscad/pull/2895), as well as a test case to prevent regression. The latest nightly builds should handle this correctly from here on out.